# Is it possible to get nx, ny, and nz values of an object's coordinates in blender?

Tags: objects, normals

So in trying to do a script that writes these values, specifically for an object's XYZ coordinates for either the direction the object is facing. I've messed with matrix stuff before in blender but I'm not quite sure how these in particular would work.

Edit:
NX, NY, NZ determine the direction the object is facing by calculating the normal the triangle the point is over.

Comment: Please elaborate on what nx, ny and nz are.

Comment: Alright I updated the post

Comment: The global vectors of the local axes?

Comment: Yes the  global vectors of the local axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Global representation of normal axes.**

The global value of the  z axis `z_axis = Vector((0, 0, 1))` of an object `obj` can be calculated using

```
nz = obj.matrix_world * z_axis
```

All can be calculated from the matrix world using,

```
nx, ny, nz =  [v.normalized() for v in obj.matrix_world.to_3x3().transposed()]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Normals" are used to tell which way a set of vertices are facing.

On the other hand, something that has been "normalized" has been scaled to 1 unit, and/or it's location brought to the origin.

I'm guessing neither of these suit your needs.
It sounds like you want an object's local coordinates, possibly rotation as well.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
x,y,z = obj.matrix_local.to_translation()
roll,pitch,yaw = obj.matrix_local.to_euler()
```

Rotation is measured in radians.  Can be converted with Python's math.degrees() if need be.